# java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/localytics/android/BuildConfig.class

Tags: android, adobecreativesdk

I'm having this error when integrating `Adobe Creative SDK`. The problem seems to come from `Localytics` library inside the Creative SDK.

> Error:Execution failed for task ':app:transformClassesWithJarMergingForDebug'.
>   com.android.build.api.transform.TransformException: java.util.zip.ZipException: duplicate entry: com/localytics/android/BuildConfig.class

This seems to happen because we are also using `Localytics` in our project but I found out that the one in the Creative SDK is older version (Ver. 2) than the one in our project (Ver. 4)

Comment: Did u find answer for that?

Comment: Hi @karan unfortunately no. I had to choose another Image editor so I removed the Creative SDK.

Comment: I resolved by removing Localytics...since localytics was not relating to edit feature. can you tell me about another Image Editor also.

Comment: @karan, I built my own image editor with the help of this library https://github.com/CyberAgent/android-gpuimage

Answer (score 0):

You can use this command at the Android Studio Terminal:

**1**

```
./gradlew :app:dependencies
```

**2**

```
./gradlew clean (Android ---> Clean the Project)
```

**3**

```
./gradlew clean assembleDebug | ./gradlew clean:assembleDebug
```

Let me know if this works! I fixed my project or if you need something more  clear.